# Alguém sabe como fazer um Web Scraping no site do SICONV (Acesso Livre) - Com o R?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

estou tentando extrair as informações do site do siconv que trata de convênios no R:

- https://www.convenios.gov.br/siconv/ForwardAction.do?modulo=programa&path=/ConsultarPrograma/ConsultarPrograma.do&Usr=guest&Pwd=guest
- http://portal.convenios.gov.br/acesso-livre

Acontece que, quando uso no R, com os pacotes rvest e httr ele redireciona para a tela de login localizado em https://idp.convenios.gov.br/idp/.

Eu tentei usar algo sobre JavaScript que tem neste post (https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-javascript-rendered-sites/) mas sem sucesso também.

Ainda não tenho grande Know-how no assunto de Web Scraping no R, mas sei me virar com algumas coisas. Minha ideia com a captura no siconv é fazer futuramente uma busca por ano dos programas disponíveis. 
Mas a princípio, eu teria que ter a mesma saída que tenho no navegar dentro do R. 
O site citado acima oferece dados para baixar, mas minha intenção é pegar algumas informações que não constam nos dados baixados.

Eu penso que o site usa cookies ou algo do tipo para certificar que é um computador e depois concede o acesso ao formulário. Preciso pelo menos chegar nesse formulário.
Se alguém tiver alguma ideia para me dar acerca disso.

Comment: Pablo, alguns sites armazenam informações sobre a segmentação das páginas na URL, processo mais simples de webscrapping. Noutros, as informações de buscas vão por outro formato, chamado POST.  Dê uma olhada  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.3.1/topics/POST

Comment: Entendi Daniel, Obrigado. Isso já é uma luz no fim do túnel. Agora, o desafio é compreender e aplicar esse método do POST e verificar se funcionará.

Comment: Quais dados você precisa?

Comment: Bom, esses dados são bem variados. Mas a ideia é ter um sistema automatizado para indicar se meu estado (RO) está apto a receber um daqueles programas disponibilizados no SICONV. Quando acesso aquele site, digito 2018 e aparece uma lista de programas e dentro deles é que quero resgatar se RO está apta ou não, é nesse sentido. Futuramente irei buscar mais dados.

Comment: Inspecionando o código, para acesso ao formulário ele fica nesse link: (javascript:window.location=getPath()+'/ForwardAction.do?modulo=Principal&path=/MostraPrincipalConsultarPrograma.do?Usr=guest&Pwd=guest'). Só que não sei o que quer dizer.

Comment: abre a aba network do navegador e manda o form. vc vai ver exatamente o que o browser faz. pelo que vi por aqui é um POST mandando o form e o cookie da sessão.

Comment: Consegui renderizar a página de formulário como no meu navegador, assim como em [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922733/10749690)  . Agora, próximo passo vai ser submeter com os dados que preciso e extrair as informações. No caso para 2018 os programas.